# How do I scale an entire view controller to work on different screen sizes

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, imageview, screen-size

Hello all i have a view controller with two text views an image view and a button they all look great on 4 inch which is what I designed it for but 3.5 inch displays are not displayed propely. so how can i have all the content from the view be seen properly on a 3.5 inch screen, I made all the parts through the storyboard. Thanks in advance!

[image: The good]

[image: notso good]

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your storyboard under the utilities panel on the right. Go to the attributes inspector and under the headline 'view' play around with the 'mode'. 'Aspect fill' and 'center' have both worked for me. Again, play around with the different view settings to see which looks best.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys i figured it out, If you're just using the storyboard then you'll need to use constraints[image: constraints bar]